# EF One to Zero or One relationship on existing tables leads to error on database updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Entity Framework 6 - Code First.
We have existing classes with their tables on our database for a while. These tables already contains data we can not delete.

We try to add "one to zero-or-one" relationship between them as follows:

```
public class Session
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual User User { get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ForeignKey("Session")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Session Session { get; set;}
}
```

This is the migration it created according to the above changes:

```
public partial class AddingSessionAndDialogOneToOneRelation : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Users", "Id", "dbo.Sessions", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Users", "Id", "dbo.Sessions");
        DropIndex("dbo.Users", new[] { "Id" });
    }
}
```

But when we run Update-Database command, we get this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Sessions_Id". The conflict occurred in database "SVC_AAA", table "dbo.Sessions", column 'Id'.

Comment: If you have a one to zero or one relationship, it doesn't work with foreign keys...

Comment: @AntoinePelletier What should I do then?

Comment: You can't have `ForeignKey` attributes on both ends, I guess `Session` is optional in your case, so remove the FK attribute from your `User` PK.

Comment: @FlorianHaider I've tried this. It generates the same migration and the same error.

Comment: Don't use foreign key at all, just imagine your foreign key without creating it, just a field without constraints that is the int representing the id of the other table

Comment: I just tested your example without the FK in `User`, and EF correctly created a migration with only one FK from `Session` to `User`.

Comment: @FlorianHaider I think it managed to create this relationship because the tables weren't filled with data. If you try to apply this relationship on filled tables, it'll probably failed.

Comment: How you classes / tables looks w/o this modification? Everything the same, just no one-to-one navigation properties? And both PKs being `Identity` columns? If yes, how are you planning to relate them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating the class definition and the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute on both Ids could also be causing the problem. It should probably only be on the User Id, but you don't need it at all if you follow the Code-First key convention.

The following code works great without additional DataAnnotations:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress Address { get; set; }

}

public class StudentAddress 
{
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

You can find lots of using examples for creating code first relationships at: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

**Update:**

For more complex classes, try the following:

```
public class Session
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual User User { get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Session Session { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This is the classic, basic, model definition. Sure it works since it is very simple. EF can predicts rules from the simple model and generate the database accordingly. e.g: It will define the Student.StudentId as a primary key & not null & identity automatically without you have to announce it explicitly.  When things come more complex and the model class needs more relationships and contains more data (as in the real world) we must tell EF rules and relationships explicitly.

Comment: However, as I wrote, I tried to define it in this style but got an error on migration creation that I have to define this relationship explicitly via mappings or data annotations. But thank you for that.

Comment: What error did you get when you defined it in this way? was it the same error or a different one?

Comment: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Web_Model.User' and 'Web_Model.Session'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: I updated the post with how the annotations should be for your classes. That should give you the 1 to 0 or 1 model that you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I tried that, it generates the same migration with the same error. I'm sorry for that, thank you for your effort to help.